# Does bit-shift depend on endianness?

Tags: c, endianness

Suppose I have the number `'numb'=1025 [00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001]` represented:

On Little-Endian Machine:

```
00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000
```

On Big-Endian Machine:

```
00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001
```

Now, if I apply Left Shift on 10 bits (i.e.: numb <<= 10), I should have:

[A] On Little-Endian Machine:

As I noticed in GDB, Little Endian does the Left Shift in 3 steps: [I have shown '3' Steps to better understand the processing only]

1. Treat the no. in Big-Endian Convention:

   ```
   00000000        00000000        00000100    00000001
   ```
2. Apply Left-Shift:

   ```
   00000000        00010000        00000100        00000000
   ```
3. Represent the Result again in Little-Endian:

   ```
   00000000        00000100        00010000        00000000
   ```

[B]. On Big-Endian Machine:

```
00000000        00010000        00000100        00000000
```

---

My Question is:

If I directly apply a Left Shift on the Little Endian 
Convention, it should give:

`numb`:

```
00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000
```

`numb << 10`:

```
00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

But actually, it gives:

```
00000000        00000100        00010000        00000000
```

To achieve the second result only, I have shown three hypothetical steps above.

Please explain me why the above two results are different: The actual outcome of `numb << 10` is different than the expected outcome.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Endianness is the way values are stored in memory. When loaded into the processor, regardless of endianness, the bit shift instruction is operating on the value in the processor's register. Therefore, loading from memory to processor is the equivalent of converting to big endian, the shifting operation comes next and then the new value is stored back in memory, which is where the little endian byte order comes into effect again.

Update, thanks to @jww: On PowerPC the vector shifts and rotates are endian sensitive. You can have a value in a vector register and a shift [will produce different results on little-endian and big-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342218/13760).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please suggest some reference where I can get a better understanding of such intricacies.

Comment: The best thing for understanding endianness is to really use it on different architectures at an embedded level. However, I could refer you to these two articles: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/endianness.aspx and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: So my code will work regardless of endian?! this is great! I've been SO worried I'd have to hack my code to hell and back!

Comment: @MarcusJ: Not necessarily. For example, if you're reading 4 bytes from a file that represent a 32-bit integer, you need to consider the endianness of the data you're reading in conjunction with the endianness of the system receiving the data in order to properly interpret the data.

Comment: Just confirmed this the hard way.  I was wondering why a 16-bit little endian number 1 in memory (0b0000000100000000) kept coming up as (0b0000000000000000) when shifted right by one.  It turns out that there's no concept of bytes in the registers.  It's just 16 bits of straight data.  This means that my number was was being loaded as (0b0000000000000001) and then being shifted right out of the register.

Comment: On PowerPC the vector shifts and rotates are endian sensitive. You can have a value in a vector register and a shift will produce different results on little-endian and big-endian.

Comment: @Carl - Yeah, PowerPC is a frustrating platform to learn. The worse part is, IBM does not document it in its references. Also see [Is vec_sld endian sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46341923/608639)

Comment: @jww But are not vector shifts a special thing which you would only access through a library or assembly? That doesn’t apply to the normal C `>>` or `<<` operator, right?

Comment: @binki - That's kind of an interesting question. You gain access to the vector unit through intrinsics. The API consists of C datatypes and functions. GCC and XLC provide overloads so you are supposed to be able to use familiar operators like `+`, `-` and `^` (I don't recall `<<` or `>>`). The problem is, they rarely work and usually arrive at the wrong result. In fact I tried to use the operator overloads at [`lea.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/lea-simd.cpp#L555). It failed miserably, and I had to go back to the C-style functions like `vec_add` and `vec_sld`.

Answer (score 76):

No, bitshift, like any other part of C, is defined in terms of *values*, not representations. Left-shift by 1 is mutliplication by 2, right-shift is division. (As always when using bitwise operations, beware of signedness. Everything is most well-defined for unsigned integral types.)

Comment: This is basically true for integer arithmetic, but C does provide plenty of cases of representation-dependent behaviour.

Comment: @Edmund: Hm... most notably the implementation of signedness is not specified, and as a consequence the behaviour of bitwise operations (like right-shift) and of modulo and divide are implementation defined on negative integers. What other things have you in mind which are implementation-defined?

Comment: @KerrekSB unfortunately they're not implementation defined on negative integers. They are unspecified in C89 and undefined in C99+, which was a very bad idea.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini: Yes, good point. Actually that's even better, since it reinforces the point that the shift operations are defined in terms of values, possibly being undefined when the result is not representable, and that speculating about the underlying representation doesn't help.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the thing is that everyone actually needs left shift to be represented both as values and as representation, depending on the case. And using unsigned integers can cause other issues, for example `x &= -1u << 20` will most likely be incorrect if `x` is 64-bit and `int` is 32-bit. For this reason, GCC promises to never treat signed shifts as undefined or even unspecified.

Answer (score 12):

Whichever shift instruction shifts out the higher-order bits first is considered the left shift.  Whichever shift instruction shifts out the lower-order bits first is considered the right shift.  In that sense, the behavior of `>>` and `<<` for `unsigned` numbers will not depend on endianness.

Comment: This specific way of explaining it is exactly what I needed to read - thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Though the accepted answer points out that endianess is a concept from the memory view. But I don't think that answer the question directly.

Some answers tell me that *bitwise operations don't depend on endianess*, and the processor may represent the bytes in any other way. Anyway, it's talking about that endianess gets abstracted.

But when we do some bitwise calculations on the paper for example, don't need to state the endianess in the first place? Most times we choose an endianess implicitly.

For example, assume we have a line of code like this

`0x1F & 0xEF`

How would you calculate the result by hand, on a paper?

```
  MSB   0001 1111  LSB
        1110 1111
result: 0000 1111
```

So here we use a Big Endian format to do the calculation. You can also use Little Endian to calculate and get the same result.

Btw, when we write numbers in code, I think it's like a Big Endian format. `123456` or `0x1F`, most significant numbers starts from the left.

Again, as soon as we write some a binary format of a value on the paper, I think we've already chosen an Endianess and we are viewing the value as we see it from the memory.

So back to the question, an shift operation `<<` should be thought as **shifting from LSB(least significant byte) to MSB(most significant byte)**.

Then as for the example in the question:

`numb=1025`

Little Endian

`LSB 00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000 MSB`

So `<< 10` would be `10bit` shifting from LSB to MSB.

---

Comparison and `<< 10` operations for Little Endian format step by step:

```
MSB                                        LSB
    00000000  00000000  00000100  00000001  numb(1025)
    00000000  00010000  00000100  00000000  << 10

LSB                                        MSB
    00000000  00000100  00010000  00000000 numb(1025) << 10, and put in a Little Endian Format

LSB                                        MSB
    00000001  00000100  00000000  00000000 numb(1205) in Little Endian format
    00000010  00001000  00000000  00000000 << 1 
    00000100  00010000  00000000  00000000 << 2 
    00001000  00100000  00000000  00000000 << 3 
    00010000  01000000  00000000  00000000 << 4
    00100000  10000000  00000000  00000000 << 5
    01000000  00000000  00000001  00000000 << 6
    10000000  00000000  00000010  00000000 << 7
    00000000  00000001  00000100  00000000 << 8
    00000000  00000010  00001000  00000000 << 9
    00000000  00000100  00010000  00000000 << 10 (check this final result!)
```

Wow! I get the expected result as the OP described!

The problems that the OP didn't get the expected result are that:

1. It seems that he didn't shift from LSB to MSB.
2. When shifting bits in Little Endian format, you should realize(thank god I realize it) that:

`LSB 10000000 00000000 MSB << 1` is
`LSB 00000000 00000001 MSB`, **not**
`LSB 01000000 00000000 MSB`

Because for each individual `8bits`, we are actually writing it in a `MSB 00000000 LSB` Big Endian format.

So it's like

`LSB[ (MSB 10000000 LSB) (MSB 00000000 LSB) ]MSB`

---

To sum up:

1. Though bitwise operations is said to be abstracted away blablablabla..., when we calculate bitwise operations by hand, we still need to know what endianess we are using as we write down the binary format on the paper. Also we need to make sure all the operators use the same endianess.
2. The OP didn't get the expected result is because he did the shifting wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Computers don't write numbers down the way we do. The value simply shifts. If you insist on looking at it byte-by-byte (even though that's not how the computer does it), you could say that on a little-endian machine, the first byte shifts left, the excess bits go into the second byte, and so on.

(By the way, little-endian makes more sense if you write the bytes vertically rather than horizontally, with higher addresses on top. Which happens to be how memory map diagrams are commonly drawn.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it in a different way: The question of endianness touches on the difference between *definition* vs. *notation* vs. *technical representation*

Starting with *definition:* the number formats we know are comprised of several *digits.* Each digit has a *place.* In decimal format, the least significant digit would be the single numbers 0-9, the digit on the next higher place would be the tens, then the hundreds and so on. In binary format, the least significant bit would be bit-0, which is 2^0, the bit on the next-higher place would be bit-1, which is 2^1

Because of the *commutativity of addition* the following holds:

```
1025 == 1*2^0 + 1*2^10 == 1*2^10 + 1*2^0
```

---

In a *technical representation,* each bit corresponds to some *cell* in an electrical circuit. For operations implemented in hardware, like e.g. addition, there is special wiring which (among others) will transport the *carry* of an addition to the next-higher cell. On this low, technical level, the *actual meaning* of endinanness is simple to understand: it defines **how processing cells are wired to the memory bus:** If we have a parallel bus of 64bit width, the question is: to which end of that bus is the least significant bit wired? Because, on the other side of that bus, there is a mapping to memory cells. In a little endian system, the wiring is such that the least significant bit will be connected to that line in the bus which maps to the lowest address in the memory.

---

However, most of the confusion arises from *notation* (more precisely, from a clash of notation systems). The point is, when *humans* do *occidental mathematics,* they always use some kind of notation, which is more similar to big endian. More specifically, the important point to note is the *writing direction* on paper. In all those cultures of the Occident, we are writing from left to right. Thus we conceptualise a digit on the left side as "first" and a digit on the right side as "later". And we have the habit of writing the most significant digits first. (Please note: in computer hardware, a cell or bus lane does not have the property of being "left" or "right" — it just depends on how you are looking at the circuity board)

Now comes the part which makes up most of the confusion. This stems from an completely ephemeral historical habit: At that time when computers first became more widely known and discussed in academia, it just happened that 8-bit registers were quite common. There is no deeper meaning in this, it is a random historic fact. But this led to the notion of a "Byte" to become something of a fad deeply entrenched in engineering culture. Unfortunately it was that very time, when also the foundational ideas of modern programming languages were formed and conceptualised. This causes the notion of a "Byte" (or a `char` in C parlance) to become deeply ingrained into the definition of our programming languages. And, as we all know, language shapes the way of our thinking.

Together, this shapes our habit of *grouping* the bits into groups of eight bits, and also the habit of *addressing* positions in the memory by multiples of eight bits. Now, combine this with the aforementioned habit of humans to *notate* the number representation from right to left. And voilà — total confusion results. We group the bits of a **little-endian** number in compounds of eight bits, but then we write them in our customary right-to-left notation:

```
1025 = 00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000
```

You see: here we *notate* each group of eight bits (a "byte") in *descending* order from right to left, but we arrange the groups in *ascending* order into this notation. Oh well. Admitted, this notation is well defined. Admitted, it is also a well established habit since 40 years or so. Yet to put it bluntly, this notational habit obscures and confuses the actual meaning.

It would be much more in line with the actual circuity and wiring to the bus, if we would *notate* the same **little-endinan** number as follows:

```
10000000 00100000 00000000 00000000
```

But it's probably too late to change such deeply ingrained habits, and so we'll have to live with that confusing "flip" in the direction within each Byte. And with the further confusion that the *direction* of **Shift operations** just happens to be defined in the mathematical notation with the most significant bit first, most left, and thus a "left shift" moves the bits up towards places with higher significance.