# Right shifting in c programming.

Tags: c, gcc, c99, endianness

Consider the expression x>>y , here x is signed int with left most bit is 1 then is the result depend on machine ?
I have tried for signed int with left most bit is 0 i got same result, but i don't know about given case.

Comment: no, but if you access a 32 bit word with an array of characters you need to be concerned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Bit Shift Depends on Endianness?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184789/does-bit-shift-depends-on-endianness)

Comment: in C bit shifts are an arithmetic operation; so they work on values, not representations

Comment: ok, that means shifting is only depend on compiler not on machine, am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

There are no unambiguous "leftmost" or "rightmost" bits (which depends on convention), but most significant and least significant bits. The sign bit on a 2's complement machine is the most significant bit.

---

`>>` uses zero extension if the shifted is an `unsigned`.

Positive signed values behave like positive unsigned values. The `>>` of a negative quantity, however, is implementation defined, but wherever I have used it, negative numbers have been sign-extended.

Also, left-shifting something to the sign bit of a signed quantity is undefined behaviour, so for most portable programs it is best to use bitshift tricks only to unsigned values.

Comment: further info; The sign bit is the MSB in all representations supported by C  (2's comp, 1's comp, sign-magnitude). so you can just say it is always the MSB.