# Hexadecimal numbers and logic operators

Tags: hex, pascal, boolean-logic, endianness

Problem to solve:

> Write hexadecimal value of 32-bit variable `i` (type Longint) after
>   executing code in Pascal. Code will translate for little-endian
>   platform. `i:=-20; i:=($FFFF xor (i shr 2)) and not($50 shl 16);`

What I need to know: what happens in brackets (`i shr 2`) and (`$50 shl 16`).

What I thought: i (-20) in hexadecimal: FFEC (but maybe thanks to little-endian it's CEFF).
($50 shl 16) - I thought that because $50 is only 8 bit, shl 16 will just make it to zero. Or will it become $500000?

Comment: This is ambiguous, and depends on the type of the integer type (since the result of "$50 shl 16" depends on with how many bits it is evaluated). Might give different results in Turbo pascal (16-bits registers and evaluation) and freepascal (32-bit evaluation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i shr 2` = shift right i by 2 positions, which is roughly i = i / 4

`$50 shl 16` = shift left $50 by 16 positions, this is done in the register (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184789/does-bit-shift-depends-on-endianness))

```
$0000 0050 -> $0050 0000
```

Now going for the calculation of `i`:

The -20 of a 32 bit value:

```
$ffff ffec
```

The SHR 2 of -20: (done in register)

```
ffff ffec -> 3fff fffb
```

Then the XOR (done in register)

```
0000 ffff
3fff fffb
----------
3fff 0004
```

Then the NOT of $0050 0000: (logical not = bit complement, not 2 complement)

```
0050 0000 -> ffaf ffff
```

Finally the AND: (in register)

```
3fff 0004
ffaf ffff
--------
3faf 0004
```

This is the value of 'i', as used in any register based calculation.

The little endianness only matters for the memory storage, 
where `i` is stored as 0400 af3f.

Comment: Isn't the value of i brought from memory, where it is written in little endian?

Comment: The expression `i:=-20; i:=($FFFF xor (i shr 2)) and not($50 shl 16);` is independent from the endianess. A debugger would show the value $3faf0004 for i and if it displayed a memory dump there would be the bytes "0400af3f" visible