# Record aggregate with dynamic choice

Tags: ada

I need to write a value consisting of all `0` except for bit `Bit` in a hardware register, where the register is somewhat like

```
type Bit_Number is range 0 .. 31;
type Bits_1 is array (Bit_Number) of Boolean
with
  Component_Size => 1,
  Size => 32;

Register_1 : Bits_1
  with
    Volatile,
    Address => System'To_Address (16#1234_5678#);
```

`Register_1` (typical of registers in Atmel's ATSAM3X8E, as in the Arduino Due) is defined as write-only, and it's unspecified what you get back if you read it, and it's unspecified what access widths are legal; all we are told is that when we write to the register only the `1` bits have any effect. (Incidentally, this means that the GNAT-specific aspect `Volatile_Full_Access` or the changes proposed in [AI12-0128](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai12s/ai12-0128-1.txt?rev=1.11&raw=N) won't help).

Enabling a pin in a GPIO peripheral involves setting its `Bit` in several registers. For reasons which I can't change ([AdaCore's SVD2Ada](https://github.com/AdaCore/svd2ada)), each register has its own equivalent of the `Bits_1` array type above.

I want to write

```
procedure Set_Bit (Bit : Bit_Number) is
begin
   Register_1 := (Bit => True, others => False);
   Register_2 := (Bit => True, others => False);
   ...
end Set_Bit;
```

but the compiler says

```
19.    procedure Set_Bit (Bit : Bit_Number) is
20.    begin
21.       Register_1 := (Bit => True, others => False);
                         |
    >>> dynamic or empty choice in aggregate must be the only choice
```

which is a reference to [ARM 4.3.3(17)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-3-3.html#p17),

> The discrete_choice_list of an array_component_association is allowed to have a discrete_choice that is a nonstatic choice_expression or that is a subtype_indication or range that defines a nonstatic or null range, only if it is the single discrete_choice of its discrete_choice_list, and there is only one array_component_association in the array_aggregate.

I can work round this,

```
procedure Set_Bit (Bit : Bit_Number) is
begin
   declare
      B : Bits_1 := (others => False);
   begin
      B (Bit) := True;
      Register_1 := B;
   end;
   ... ad nauseam
end Set_Bit;
```

but this seems very clumsy! Any other suggestions?

Comment: I assume that there is a reason you don't just do `Register (J) := True`, but also explicitly set the other fields to `False`.  Except for that, I can't come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: **Apologies** for a major edit; I thought I was being helpful by abstracting the problem, but I went too far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be an array?
An alternative could be:

```
with Interfaces;
procedure Set_Bit is
   Register : Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
begin
   for J in 0..31 loop
      Register := 2**J;
   end loop;
end Set_Bit;
```

Comment: This is certainly a possibility, given that SVD2Ada actually generates an unchecked union of the array view and an unsigned view.

Comment: This is the solution I adopted. In different circumstances [Jacob’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36186932/40851) might be better.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this can be a little cumbersome , but if you need an array you could initialize it as a whole using concatenated sliced aggregates:

```
    for J in 0 .. 31 loop
       Register := Bits'(others => False)(0..J-1) &
                   True & Bits'(others => False)(J+1..31);
    end loop;
```

Comment: This would work .. will try it out to see if it’s bearable!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a candidate for a function:

```ada
function Single_Bit (Set : in Bit_Number) return Bits_1 is
begin
   return Result : Bits_1 := (others => False) do
      Result (Set) := True;
   end return;
end Single_Bit;
```

And then:

```ada
Register_1 := Single_Bit (Set => Some_Bit);
Register_2 := Single_Bit (Set => Another_Bit);
```

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion; the trouble in my context is that SVD2Ada declares each register with its own array type!

Answer (score 0):

## [Example 1](https://ideone.com/hgmWa3)

This uses the [`Shift_Left`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-B-2.html) operation.

```vhdl
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;

procedure Main_Test is
   function One_Bit (Index : Natural) return Unsigned_32 is (Shift_Left (1, Index));

   type Bit_Array_32_Index is range 0 .. 31;
   type Bit_Array_17_Index is range 0 .. 16;
   type Bit_Array_32 is array (Bit_Array_32_Index) of Boolean with Component_Size => 1, Size => 32;
   type Bit_Array_17 is array (Bit_Array_17_Index) of Boolean with Component_Size => 1, Size => 17;

   -- For every new array type instantiate a convert function.
   function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Unsigned_32, Bit_Array_32);
   function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Unsigned_32, Bit_Array_17);
   B32 : Bit_Array_32 with Volatile;
   B17 : Bit_Array_17 with Volatile;
begin
   B17 := Convert (One_Bit (2)) or Convert (One_Bit (5));
   B32 := Convert (One_Bit (2) or One_Bit (5));
   for E of B17 loop
      Put (Boolean'Pos (E), 1);
   end loop;
   New_Line;
   for E of B32 loop
      Put (Boolean'Pos (E), 1);
   end loop;
end;
```

### Result

```
00100100000000000
00100100000000000000000000000000
```

### Warnings

```
main.adb:21:04: warning: types for unchecked conversion have different sizes
main.adb:21:04: warning: size of "Unsigned_32" is 32, size of "Bit_Array_17" is 17
main.adb:21:04: warning: 15 high order bits of source will be ignored
```

---

## [Example generics](https://ideone.com/QbfzLp)

This uses the [`Shift_Left`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-B-2.html) operation but with generics.

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;

procedure Main is
   package Unsigned_32_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO (Unsigned_32);

   type Bit_Array_32_Index is range 0 .. 31;
   type Bit_Array_17_Index is range 0 .. 16;
   type Bit_Array_32 is array (Bit_Array_32_Index) of Boolean with Component_Size => 1, Size => 32;
   type Bit_Array_17 is array (Bit_Array_17_Index) of Boolean with Component_Size => 1, Size => 32;

   generic
      type I is (<>);
      type T is array (I) of Boolean;
   procedure Generic_Put (Item : T; Width : Field; Base : Number_Base);
   procedure Generic_Put (Item : T; Width : Field; Base : Number_Base) is
      function Convert_To_Unsigned_32 is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (T, Unsigned_32);
   begin
      Unsigned_32_IO.Put (Convert_To_Unsigned_32 (Item), Width, Base);
   end;

   generic
      type I is (<>);
      type T is array (I) of Boolean;
   function Generic_Shift_Left (Value : Unsigned_32; Amount : Natural) return T;
   function Generic_Shift_Left (Value : Unsigned_32; Amount : Natural) return T is
      function Convert_To_Bit_Array_32 is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Unsigned_32, T);
   begin
      return Convert_To_Bit_Array_32 (Interfaces.Shift_Left (Value, Amount));
   end;

   function Shift_Left is new Generic_Shift_Left (Bit_Array_32_Index, Bit_Array_32);
   function Shift_Left is new Generic_Shift_Left (Bit_Array_17_Index, Bit_Array_17);
   procedure Put is new Generic_Put (Bit_Array_32_Index, Bit_Array_32);
   procedure Put is new Generic_Put (Bit_Array_17_Index, Bit_Array_17);

   B32 : Bit_Array_32 with Volatile;
   B17 : Bit_Array_17 with Volatile;
begin
   B32 := Shift_Left (1, 2) or Shift_Left (1, 5);
   B17 := Shift_Left (1, 2) or Shift_Left (1, 5);
   Put (B17, 0, 2);
   New_Line;
   Put (B32, 0, 2);
end;
```

### Result

```
2#100100#
2#100100#
```

---

## gprbuild -v

```
GPRBUILD GPL 2015 (20150428) (i686-pc-mingw32)
```

## Questions

Does it work on big-endian machine?
I haven't tested. See [does bit-shift depend on endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184789/does-bit-shift-depend-on-endianness)

Comment: I think this might not work on a big-endian machine. Doesn’t your compiler warn on UC between objects of different size?

Comment: @SimonWright I tested Bit_Array_17 just to see if it works. I guess 32 bit data will be written to a Bit_Array_17 and the rest of the 15 bits will be written outside the Bit_Array_17 variable.

Comment: @Jossi I tested it now with a packed record containing Bit_Array_17 and Bit_Array_15 then write 32 bit to Bit_Array_17 result is: Bit_Array_15 is not affected. But writing 32 bit to the record will affect both Bit_Array_17 and Bit_Array_15. [Test](https://ideone.com/tdISM7).