# Get bit offset in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, offset

I have an `int` parameter with the possible values 1,2,4,8,16,32,64.

I need to know the bit offset of the current value, i.e. for each value return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 respectively.

What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you mean powers of two (6 isn’t one)? In which case the “bit offset” would be the logarithm base 2?

Comment: Yes, please clarify. Best regards,

Comment: The naive approach is to loop and test, but it's possible that there's a native CPU instruction that does this in one single instruction. ("get least (or most) significant bit")

Comment: Sorry, the 6 should not be there, I know solve this using: log((double)val) / log(2.0);  but I think this is not the right approach

Comment: MSVC: _BitScanForward  GCC: __builtin_ctz  (easiest because you don't actually have to write any code, just call a function that already exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple answers here : http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious
the easiest being, assuming you have your input value in an unsigned int v :

```
unsigned int r = 0; // r will be lg(v)

while (v >>= 1) // unroll for more speed...
{
  r++;
}
```

but it will change v in the process.

edit: in your case if you are 100% sure your input is and int and a power of 2, a look-up-table may be the simplest and fastest

Comment: What has endianess got to do with it?

Comment: I am rather certain that your code is correct without any regard to the endianness of the hardware system on which it is running.

Comment: ok according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness endianness is not an issue, I edited my reply

Comment: Luckily it has nothing to do with endianness, otherwise we would be royally scr*wed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that only does five iterations at most for a 32 bit value, unlike lezebulon's answer which has a worst case of 32 iterations. Adapting to 64 bit values increases the iteration count of this version to six and the other to 64 at worst.

```
int get_pos (unsigned v)
{
  int s=16,p=0,m=0xffff;

  while (s)
  {
    if (v>>s) p += s;
    v = (v | (v >> s)) & m;
    s >>= 1;
    m >>= s;
  }

  return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop and shift a bit each time. But there's a faster way using switch case. listing both for you.

```
//more code but awesomely fast
int getBitOffset1(int d) {
  switch(d) {
    case 1: return 1;
    case 2: return 2;
    case 4: return 3;
    case 8: return 4;
    case 16: return 5;
    case 32: return 6;
    /* keep adding case upto sizeof int*8 */
  }
}

//less code, the loop goes 64 times max
int getBitOffset2(int d) {
  int seed=0x01;
  int retval=0;
  do{
    if(seed<<retval == d) {
      break;
    }
    retval++;
  }while(retval<=sizeof(int)*8);
  return retval+1;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", getBitOffset2(32));
    printf("%d\n", getBitOffset2(1));
    return 0;
}
```