# last 5 bits of a bitmask

Tags: c#

I have a bitmask (stored as a short). For various purposes, I want to zero out all but the last 5 bits - I'm sure there is an easy to way to do this via bitwise operators, but it eludes me.

```
1010 01101 1011 0111 -> 0000 0000 0001 0111
```

Thanks

Comment: Remember / Respect teh Endianess!!! Regardless of what they tell you ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use something like:

```
x & 0x1f
```

In binary, your example would be:

```
    1010 1101 1011 0111
  & 0000 0000 0001 1111
  ---------------------
    0000 0000 0001 0111
```

When using the `&` operator, 0 bits in the mask result in 0 bits in the result. 1 bits in the mask copy the corresponding bits to the result.

Comment: Since type very well could be stored in PDP-Endian I am down voting for not giving advice to perform binary operations according to endianess although it might involve common sense. Although you did give a binary example you could have also shown and told the obvious.

Comment: @Jay: Bitwise logical operations are independent of endianness. Endianness only makes a difference when values are stored in memory - once they are loaded into CPU registers, there is no difference. Your objection is specious.

Comment: As I stated below...  his example is loaded into memory so... 'The latter may be true but your example is shifting from loaded memory hence the address of notation used ;P'

Answer (score 1):

Value =  OriginalValue & 0x1F

Comment: What about it? Variable and literal aren't going to differ are they?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
your_variable_name & ((1 << 5) - 1)
```

(1 << 5) - 1 will give you a 11111, and then you and it with your value.

Comment: yeah also the operator precedence was messed up.  fixed both.

Comment: @Jay: no it wouldn't.  Not in this case.

Comment: Well being as var is not valid in C I assumed that a auto conversion was happening and that the size of the pointer was not the size of the int for a weird reason but I could also just remove my comment :p None the less thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Jay var was supposed to be just a generic variable name.  I forgot that it might be a reserved word.

Comment: @jay sir, you are insane.  Bit shift operators take big/little endinan into account.

Comment: @Jay finding a good explanation was surprisingly difficult, but here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1041573/68105

Comment: The latter may be true but your example is shifting from loaded memory hence the address of notation used ;P And thank you for the compliment... I up voted your reply!

Comment: @Jay shifting from loaded memory?  Address of notation?  I don't follow.

Comment: Shifting was the wrong term, I meant applying a binary operation to...  and I can't argument anymore for 2 reasons... 1 I am high and 2 I am tired :p