# Convert Bytes to Int / uint in C

Tags: c, arrays, serialization, int, byte

I have a unsigned char array[248]; filled with bytes. Like 2F AF FF 00 EB AB CD EF .....
This Array is my Byte Stream which I store my Data from the UART (RS232) as a Buffer.

Now I want to convert the bytes back to my uint16's and int32's.

In C# I used the BitConverter Class to do this. e.g:

```
byte[] Array = { 0A, AB, CD, 25 };
int myint1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
int myint2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
int myint3 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 8);
int myint4 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 12);
//...
enter code here
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", myint1); //output Data...
```

Is there a similiar Function in C ?  (no .net , I use the KEIL compiler because code is running on a microcontroller)

With Regards
Sam

Comment: This site uses a Question and Answer format - please do not edit the question to contain answers.  Also the answer that you had edited into the question was wrong anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is. Assume your bytes are in:

```
uint8_t bytes[N] = { /* whatever */ };
```

We know that, a 16 bit integer is just two 8 bit integers concatenated, i.e. one has a multiple of 256 or alternatively is shifted by 8:

```
uint16_t sixteen[N/2];

for (i = 0; i < N; i += 2)
    sixteen[i/2] = bytes[i] | (uint16_t)bytes[i+1] << 8;
             // assuming you have read your bytes little-endian
```

Similarly for 32 bits:

```
uint32_t thirty_two[N/4];

for (i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
    thirty_two[i/4] = bytes[i] | (uint32_t)bytes[i+1] << 8
        | (uint32_t)bytes[i+2] << 16 | (uint32_t)bytes[i+3] << 24;
             // same assumption
```

---

If the bytes are read big-endian, of course you reverse the order:

```
bytes[i+1] | (uint16_t)bytes[i] << 8
```

and

```
bytes[i+3] | (uint32_t)bytes[i+2] << 8
    | (uint32_t)bytes[i+1] << 16 | (uint32_t)bytes[i] << 24
```

Note that there's a difference between the endian-ness in the stored integer and the endian-ness of the running architecture. The endian-ness referred to in this answer is of the stored integer, i.e., the contents of `bytes`. The solutions are independent of the endian-ness of the running architecture since [endian-ness is taken care of when shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041554/912144).

Comment: then you shift in the least significant bits instead the most significant bits.

Comment: @twall, I think you mean bytes.

Comment: @sam, see my edit. Also, try reading a little on binary numbers. What I am doing is simple multiplication.

Comment: stupid question, but my Array[100] is a char array, but does it matter because you guys wrote uint8_t bytes[N]

Comment: @sam, if `char` on your system is signed, then yes, it matters. Imagine `0xFF`. If you viewed as signed, it's -1. So instead of adding to 255, you will be subtracting by 1, which is not what you would want. `unsigned char` is the same as `uint8_t` by the way.

Comment: I uploaded my Debug-Output http://s18.postimage.org/fipv7svp3/debugbyte.png when I tried Ethans way. It seems, that the other bytes will not fill ... now im trying your way.

Comment: @sam, is `RXBUFF` your received bytes? The other solution doesn't work because they type of your array is `int` instead of `unsigned char`.

Comment: yep RXBUFF are my recieved bytes (unsignec char array), but i can change the datatype of the array.

Comment: OK guys it works with using a uint8_t BufferArray[] ... now it works fine! I testet it with the number 1985 (my birthday)  as uint16 and uint32

Comment: I'd cast each `bytes[]` to a `uint32_t` before shifting it.  As written above, they'll be cast to `int`s before doing the shifts, but `int` need not be 32 bits.

Comment: Your debug photo shows the type of `RXBUFF` as `int[248]`! @JoshuaGreen, you are right.

Comment: Is it me, or am i the only one that's having to use a bit mask to make this work.  For some reason my 2 inner bytes of a 4-byte int seem to be accumulating leading 1's when I bit shift them.  For example, say little-endian byte position two is `E1`, `(int)0xE1<<8` is evaluating to `4294959360` instead of `57600`.  `((int)0xE1<<8)&0x0000FF00` seems to correct it.  What am I failing to recognize here?

Comment: @hydroparadise, I think you're not telling everything. Your number is probably stored in a char, which in your system is signed, so 0xE1 is actually a negative number. Casting that to int causes the sign extention to keep the signed value unmodified. The left shift has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 44):

There's no standard function to do it for you in C.  You'll have to assemble the bytes back into your 16- and 32-bit integers yourself.  Be careful about endianness!

Here's a simple little-endian example:

```
extern uint8_t *bytes;
uint32_t myInt1 = bytes[0] + (bytes[1] << 8) + (bytes[2] << 16) + (bytes[3] << 24);
```

For a big-endian system, it's just the opposite order:

```
uint32_t myInt1 = (bytes[0] << 24) + (bytes[1] << 16) + (bytes[2] << 8) + bytes[3];
```

You might be able to get away with:

```
uint32_t myInt1 = *(uint32_t *)bytes;
```

If you're careful about alignment issues.

Comment: I'd cast each `bytes[]` to a `uint32_t` before shifting it.  As written above, they'll be cast to `int`s before doing the shifts, but `int` need not be 32 bits.

Comment: That would be safest, agreed.

Comment: Assuming `bytes` is native endian, what sort of alignment issues would you run into? Or, I guess, what kind of situations makes alignment a problem?

Comment: `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` are not compatible types and thus casting a `uint8_t*` to an `uint32_t*` violates the strict aliasing rule in C and thus inflicts undefined behaviour - and 
you mention it yourself...

Comment: @Azmisov Alignment issues have nothing to do with endianness: Its just that usually an 32bit word usually needs to be aligbed at a 32bit- boundary, while a byte (or Herr an arry of bytes...) might not be aligned that way. That's why the C standard prohibits casting a pointer to a byte to a pointer to a word...

Comment: `*(uint32_t *)bytes` causes undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation)

Comment: Thank you! The best answer! You saved my day!

Answer (score 5):

In case of little-endian, can't you just use memcpy?

```
memcpy((char*)&myint1, aesData.inputData[startindex], length);
```

Comment: The local machine isn't always little-endian.

Answer (score 1):

```
            char letter = 'A';
            size_t filter = letter;
            filter = (filter <<  8 | filter);
            filter = (filter << 16 | filter);
            filter = (filter << 32 | filter);
            printf("filter: %#I64x \n", filter);
```

result: "filter: 0x4141414141414141"

Answer (score 0):

My favourite but UB:

```
char bytes[] = {0};
sprintf(bytes, "%s", "\xAA\xBB\xCC");
uint64_t n = *(uint64_t*)bytes; // n = 0xccbbaa on little-endian
```