# how to typecast byte array to 8 byte-size integer

Tags: c, memory

I was asked an interview question: given a 6 byte input, which got from a big endian machine, please implement a function to convert/typecast it to 8 bytes, assume we do not know the endian of the machine running this function.

The point of the question seems to test my understanding of endianess because I was asked whether I know endianess before this question.

I do not know how to answer the question. e.g. do I need to pad 6 byte to 8 byte first? and how? Here is my code. is it correct?

```
 bool isBigEndian(){
  int num = 1;
  char* b = (char*)(&num);
  return b ? false:true;
 }    
 long long* convert(char* arr[]){ //size is 6
   long long* res = (long long*)malloc(long long);//...check res is NULL...
   if (isBigEnian()){  
         for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++)
           memset(res, i+2, arr[i]);
   }
   else {
         for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++)
           memset(res, i+2, arr[6-1-i]);
   }
   return res; //assume caller will free res.
 }
```

update: to answer that my question is not clear, I just found a link: [Convert Bytes to Int / uint in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240299/convert-bytes-to-int-uint-in-c) with the similar question. based on my understanding of that, endianess of the host does matters. suppose if input is: char array[] = {01,02,03,04,05,06}, then if host is little endian, output is stored as 00,00,06,05,04,03,02,01, if big endian, output will be stored as 00,00,01,02,03,04,05,06, in both case, the 0000 are padded at beginning.

I am a kind of understand now: in the other machine, suppose there is a number xyz = 010203040506  because it is bigendian and 01 is MSB. so it is stored as char array = {01,02,03,04,05,06} where 01 has lowest address. then in this machine, if the machine is also big endian. it should be stored as {00,00,01,02,03,04,05,06 } where 01 is still MSB, so that it is cast to the same number int_64 xyz2 = 0000010203040506.   but if the machine is little endian, it should be stored as {00,00,06,05,04,03,02,01 } where 01 is MSB has highest address in order for int_32 xyz2 = 0000010203040506.

please let me know if my undestanding is incorrect. and Can anybody tell me why 0000 is always padded at beginning no matter what endianess?  shouldn't it be padded at the end if this machine is little endian since 00 is Most sign byte?

Comment: To answer this question, you'd need some definition of what it means to "convert" from 6-byte to 8-byte.

Comment: Also, there is no reasonable way I can see that endianess wouldn't matter.

Comment: Maybe the point of the question was to see if you'd ask for clarification or continue on with lack of specification.

Comment: Sounds a bit like base64 encoding.

Comment: convert means how 6 byte stored in a 8 byte variable given the condition of endianess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before moving on, you should have asked for clarification.

What exactly means converting here? Padding each char with 0's? Prefixing each char with 0's?

I will assume that each char should be prefixed with 0's. This is a possible solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define DATA_WIDTH 6

uint64_t convert(unsigned char data[]) {
    uint64_t res;
    int i;
    res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < DATA_WIDTH; i++) {
        res = (res << CHAR_BIT) | data[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

To append 0's to each char, we could, instead, use this inside the for:

```
res = (res << CHAR_BIT) | (data[i] << 2);
```

In an interview, you should always note the limitations for your solution. This solution assumes that the implementation provides `uint64_t` type (it is not required by the C standard).

The fact that the input is big endian is important because it lets you know that `data[0]` corresponds to the most significant byte, and it must remain so in your result. This solution works not matter what the target machine's endianness.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you think malloc is necessary. Why not just something like this?

```
long long convert(unsigned char data[]);
{
  long long res;
  res = 0;
  for( int i=0;i < 6; ++i)
    res = (res << 8) + data[i];

  return res;
}
```