Serial.Read() of ESP32 skips 0 values when reading HEX data
I am trying to read data form my SmartMeter (Siemens IM350) and therefore i would like to use an ESP32. The SmartMeter sends data every 1 second when being called. The signal of the SmartMeter is inverted with a transistor and is read with serial2 (as the default UART0 is used for USB communication) of the ESP32.
The SmartMeter sends a data package of 114 bytes. When disabling the ESP32 (pressing the reset button) and using it as a USB interface for a PC, HTERM receives a message like this:
7EA070CF0002002313E0C7E6E700DB08534D53677001764B5620000009FF5472DF3F6384A0115A6F55B5E01D050C9CC534CA128D8EE69EDDFA6E1907F2165EF32F5586150572B800F172BB27F04558944F9A77C67CAE0F06B11ECD8494F583519A514E58180948CAA21CE69DB523AE017B7E
This message has 114 bytes and can be decrypted easily. However, using the ESP32 on its own, a shorter message is received:
7EA070CF0202313E0C7E6E70DB8534D5367701764B562000A728764BBF7916DA350DBBFE1915F4B9B93AD694A3D11A55B118440932C5A2D738A98D3B66F5B0C93AECA829CAA1EC17EF71E841F95ADE89C9E587105B2DA89ECFAB53A7CF3442D19854863C70ADBD1848277E
This message is only 107 bytes long (but it varies, some are longer some are shorter, but none are 114 bytes long). It seems that the Serial.Read() skips 0 values for some reason. This can be seen in the first 20 to 30 byts which should be identical, however zeros are missing. How can this problem be fixed?
Here is my code, it is copied and altered from esphome_im350 (the wiring can also be seen on this page):
Main:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <TelnetStream.h>
#include <Crypto.h>
#include <AES.h>
#include <GCM.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "time.h"

#include "secrets.h"
#include "settings.h"

// NTP Settings
struct tm ntpTime;
uint8_t current_time_day;
uint8_t current_time_month;
uint16_t current_time_year;

// message date variables
uint16_t message_year;
uint8_t message_month;
uint8_t message_day;
uint8_t message_hour;
uint8_t message_minute;
uint8_t message_second;

// reading variables
uint32_t counter_reading_p_in;
uint32_t counter_reading_p_out;
uint32_t counter_reading_q_in;
uint32_t counter_reading_q_out;
uint32_t current_power_usage_in;
uint32_t current_power_usage_out;

struct Vector_GCM {
    const char *name;
    uint8_t key[16];
    uint8_t ciphertext[90];
    uint8_t authdata[16];
    uint8_t iv[12];
    uint8_t tag[12];
    size_t authsize;
    size_t datasize;
    size_t tagsize;
    size_t ivsize;
};

Vector_GCM Vector_SM;
GCM<AES128> *gcmaes128 = 0;

boolean getLocalTime()
{
  if(!getLocalTime(&ntpTime)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    current_time_day = ntpTime.tm_mday;
    current_time_month = ntpTime.tm_mon + 1; // Month is 0 - 11, add 1 to get a jan-dec 1-12 concept
    current_time_year = ntpTime.tm_year + 1900; // Year is # years since 1900
    return true;
  }
}

void printLocalTime() {
  if (getLocalTime()) {
    Serial.println(&ntpTime, "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S");  
  }
}

void print_array(byte array[], unsigned int len)
{
  char text_buffer[len];

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
      byte nib1 = (array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
      byte nib2 = (array[i] >> 0) & 0x0F;
      text_buffer[i*2+0] = nib1  < 0xA ? '0' + nib1  : 'A' + nib1  - 0xA;
      text_buffer[i*2+1] = nib2  < 0xA ? '0' + nib2  : 'A' + nib2  - 0xA;
  }
  text_buffer[len*2] = '\0';
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Serial.print(text_buffer[i]);
  }
}

uint32_t byteToUInt32(byte array[], unsigned int startByte)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240299/convert-bytes-to-int-uint-in-c
    // convert 4 bytes to uint32
    uint32_t result;
    result = (uint32_t) array[startByte] << 24;
    result |=  (uint32_t) array[startByte+1] << 16;
    result |= (uint32_t) array[startByte+2] << 8;
    result |= (uint32_t) array[startByte+3];

    return result;
}

void parse_timestamp(byte array[]) {
  message_year = (array[6] << 8) + (array[7]);
  message_month = array[8];
  message_day = array[9];
  message_hour = array[11];
  message_minute = array[12];
  message_second = array[13];
}

// used to see if encrypted data are correct...
bool validate_message_date() {
  Serial.println();
  // compare date from ntp and message should be the same day!
  Serial.println();
  TelnetStream.println();
  Serial.println("======DEBUG=======");
  TelnetStream.println("======DEBUG=======");
  Serial.printf("DATE FROM NTP: %02d-%02d-%02d", current_time_year, current_time_month, current_time_day);
  TelnetStream.printf("DATE FROM NTP: %02d-%02d-%02d", current_time_year, current_time_month, current_time_day);
  Serial.println();
  TelnetStream.println();
  Serial.printf("DATE FROM MESSAGE: %02d-%02d-%02d", message_year, message_month, message_day);
  TelnetStream.printf("DATE FROM MESSAGE: %02d-%02d-%02d", message_year, message_month, message_day);
  Serial.println();
  TelnetStream.println();

  if (current_time_year == message_year and current_time_month == message_month and current_time_day == message_day){
    Serial.printf("Message Date is VALID!, ntp_date: %02d-%02d-%02d == message_date: %02d-%02d-%02d\n", current_time_year, current_time_month, current_time_day, message_year, message_month, message_day);
    TelnetStream.printf("Message Date is VALID!, ntp_date: %02d-%02d-%02d == message_date: %02d-%02d-%02d\n", current_time_year, current_time_month, current_time_day, message_year, message_month, message_day);
    Serial.println("======DEBUG=======");
    TelnetStream.println("======DEBUG=======");
    Serial.println();
    TelnetStream.println();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    Serial.printf("Message Date is INVALID!, ntp_date: %02d-%02d-%02d !=  message_date: %02d-%02d-%02d\n", current_time_year, current_time_month, current_time_day, message_year, message_month, message_day);
    TelnetStream.printf("Message Date is INVALID!, ntp_date: %02d-%02d-%02d !=  message_date: %02d-%02d-%02d\n", current_time_year, current_time_month, current_time_day, message_year, message_month, message_day);
    Serial.println("======DEBUG=======");
    TelnetStream.println("======DEBUG=======");
    Serial.println();
    TelnetStream.println();
    return false;
  }
}

int readMessage() {
    unsigned short serial_cnt = 0;
    if (use_test_data == true) {
        Serial.println("USE TEST DATA IS ACTIVE!");
        TelnetStream.println("USE TEST DATA IS ACTIVE!");
        serial_cnt = 123;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 123; i++) {
            message[i] = testData[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Try to read data from serial port.");
        TelnetStream.println("Try to read data from serial port.");
        
        memset(message, 0, message_length);

        int cnt = 0;
        int readBuffer = 250;

        pinMode(led_builtin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(data_request_gpio, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(led_builtin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(data_request_gpio,HIGH);
        unsigned long requestMillis = millis();
        delay(delay_before_reading_data);
        while ((Serial2.available()) && (cnt < readBuffer) && (millis()-requestMillis <= max_wait_time_for_reading_data)) {
          message[cnt] = Serial2.read();
          if (message[0] != start_byte && cnt == 0) {
            continue;
          }
          else {
            cnt++;
          }
        }

        digitalWrite(led_builtin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(data_request_gpio,LOW);
    }
  Serial.println("Done with reading from from serial port.");
  TelnetStream.println("Done with reading from from serial port.");
  return (serial_cnt);
}

void init_vector(Vector_GCM *vect, const char *Vect_name, byte *key_SM) {
  vect->name = Vect_name;  // vector name
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    vect->key[i] = key_SM[i];
  }


  //changed (from 90 to 81)
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    vect->ciphertext[i] = message[i+30];
  }
  byte AuthData[] = {0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xdf}; // fixed value, i got it from the gurus director software

  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
     vect->authdata[i] = AuthData[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     vect->iv[i] = message[16+i]; // manufacturer + serialnumber 8 bytes
  }
  for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
    vect->iv[i] = message[18+i]; // frame counter
  }

  byte tag[12]; // 12x zero
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    vect->tag[i] = tag[i];
  }

  vect->authsize = 16;
  vect->datasize = 81;
  vect->tagsize = 12;
  vect->ivsize  = 12;
}

void decrypt_text(Vector_GCM *vect) {
  gcmaes128 = new GCM<AES128>();
  gcmaes128->setKey(vect->key, gcmaes128->keySize());
  gcmaes128->setIV(vect->iv, vect->ivsize);
  gcmaes128->decrypt((byte*)buffer, vect->ciphertext, vect->datasize);

  // this does not work...
  // bool decryption_failed = false;
  // if (!gcmaes128->checkTag(vect->tag, vect->tagsize)) {
  //   decryption_failed = true;
  //   Serial.println("Decryption Failed!");
  // }
  // else {
  //   Serial.println("Decryption OK!");
  // }
  delete gcmaes128;
}

void parse_message(byte array[]) {

      //Changed (Number)
      counter_reading_p_in = byteToUInt32(array, 52);
      counter_reading_p_out = byteToUInt32(array, 57);
      counter_reading_q_in = byteToUInt32(array, 62);
      counter_reading_q_out = byteToUInt32(array, 67);
      current_power_usage_in = byteToUInt32(array, 72);
      current_power_usage_out = byteToUInt32(array, 77);

      // Serial.println(result, DEC);
      Serial.printf("counter_reading_p_in: %d\n", counter_reading_p_in);
      TelnetStream.printf("counter_reading_p_in: %d\n", counter_reading_p_in);
      Serial.printf("counter_reading_p_out: %d\n", counter_reading_p_out);
      TelnetStream.printf("counter_reading_p_out: %d\n", counter_reading_p_out);
      Serial.printf("counter_reading_q_in: %d\n", counter_reading_q_in);
      TelnetStream.printf("counter_reading_q_in: %d\n", counter_reading_q_in);
      Serial.printf("counter_reading_q_out: %d\n", counter_reading_q_out);
      TelnetStream.printf("counter_reading_q_out: %d\n", counter_reading_q_out);
      Serial.printf("current_power_usage_in: %d\n", current_power_usage_in);
      TelnetStream.printf("current_power_usage_in: %d\n", current_power_usage_in);
      Serial.printf("current_power_usage_out: %d\n", current_power_usage_out);
      TelnetStream.printf("current_power_usage_out: %d\n", current_power_usage_out);
}

void printBytesToHex(byte array[], unsigned int len) {
  
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Serial.print(message[i], HEX);
    TelnetStream.print(message[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.print("\n");
  TelnetStream.print("\n");
}

void SerialTelnetPrint(char msg[]) {
  Serial.println(msg);
  Serial.println(msg);
}

void setup() {
    btStop(); // disable bluetooth
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial2.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, uart2_rx_gpio, uart2_tx_gpio);
    
    //connect to WiFi
    Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", wifi_ssid);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_password);
    while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.println("Connection Failed! Rebooting...");
      delay(5000);
      ESP.restart();
    }
    

  // Port defaults to 3232
  ArduinoOTA.setPort(3232);

  // Hostname defaults to esp3232-[MAC]
  ArduinoOTA.setHostname("sm_reader");

  // No authentication by default
  // ArduinoOTA.setPassword("admin");

  // Password can be set with it's md5 value as well
  // MD5(admin) = 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
  // ArduinoOTA.setPasswordHash("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");

  ArduinoOTA
    .onStart([]() {
      String type;
      if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH)
        type = "sketch";
      else // U_SPIFFS
        type = "filesystem";

      // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
      Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
    })
    .onEnd([]() {
      Serial.println("\nEnd");
    })
    .onProgress([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) {
      Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
    })
    .onError([](ota_error_t error) {
      Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
      if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) Serial.println("Auth Failed");
      else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) Serial.println("Begin Failed");
      else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) Serial.println("Connect Failed");
      else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) Serial.println("Receive Failed");
      else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) Serial.println("End Failed");
    });


    ArduinoOTA.begin();
    Serial.println("Ready");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    //init and get the time
    configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntp_server);
    getLocalTime();
    printLocalTime();

    TelnetStream.begin();
}

void loop() {
    ArduinoOTA.handle();
    
    //init and get the time
    configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntp_server);
    getLocalTime();
    printLocalTime();
    
    Serial.printf("RSSI: %d dBm\n", WiFi.RSSI());
    TelnetStream.printf("RSSI: %d dBm\n", WiFi.RSSI());
    Serial.println(WiFi.BSSIDstr());
    TelnetStream.println(WiFi.BSSIDstr());

    readMessage();




    if (message[0] == start_byte and message[sizeof(message)-1] == stop_byte) {
      Serial.println("Got message from meter, try to decrypt.");
      TelnetStream.println("Got message from meter, try to decrypt.");
      Serial.print("ReceivedMessage: ");
      TelnetStream.print("ReceivedMessage: ");
      printBytesToHex(message, (sizeof(message)/sizeof(message[0])));

      init_vector(&Vector_SM,"Vector_SM",sm_decryption_key); 

      // print decryption details
      Serial.print("IV: ");
      TelnetStream.print("IV: ");
      printBytesToHex(Vector_SM.iv, (sizeof(Vector_SM.iv)/sizeof(Vector_SM.iv[0])));
      Serial.print("Key: ");
      TelnetStream.print("Key: ");
      printBytesToHex(Vector_SM.key, (sizeof(Vector_SM.key)/sizeof(Vector_SM.key[0])));
      Serial.print("Authdata: ");
      TelnetStream.print("Authdata: ");
      printBytesToHex(Vector_SM.authdata, (sizeof(Vector_SM.authdata)/sizeof(Vector_SM.authdata[0])));
      Serial.print("Tag: ");
      TelnetStream.print("Tag: ");
      printBytesToHex(Vector_SM.tag, (sizeof(Vector_SM.tag)/sizeof(Vector_SM.tag[0])));
      Serial.print("Encrypted Data (Ciphertext): ");
      TelnetStream.print("Encrypted Data (Ciphertext): ");
      printBytesToHex(Vector_SM.ciphertext, (sizeof(Vector_SM.ciphertext)/sizeof(Vector_SM.ciphertext[0])));

      decrypt_text(&Vector_SM);
      Serial.print("Decrypted Data: ");
      TelnetStream.print("Decrypted Data: ");
      printBytesToHex(buffer, (sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0])));

      Serial.print("======Decrypted Parsed Data======\n");
      TelnetStream.print("======Decrypted Parsed Data======\n");
      parse_message(buffer);
      Serial.print("======Decrypted Parsed Data======\n");
      TelnetStream.print("======Decrypted Parsed Data======\n");

      parse_timestamp(buffer);

      if (validate_message_date()) {
        Serial.println("Do something.");
        TelnetStream.println("Do something.");
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("Do nothing.");
        TelnetStream.println("Do nothing.");
      }

    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Message not starting/ending with 0xE7, skip this message!");
      TelnetStream.println("Message not starting/ending with 0xE7, skip this message!");
      Serial.print("Received Message: ");
      TelnetStream.print("Received Message: ");
      printBytesToHex(message, (sizeof(message)/sizeof(message[0])));
    }
    
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("waiting 1 second...");
    TelnetStream.println("waiting 1 second...");
    Serial.println("reset");
    TelnetStream.println("reset");
}

Settings.h:
// Using UART2 for reading the data from the smart meter, if you use the UART0 you can not upload new code to the board cause its blocked while reading from the meter!
int uart2_rx_gpio = 16;
int uart2_tx_gpio = 17;
int data_request_gpio = 26;
int led_builtin = 2;
// NTP Settings
char ntp_server[] = "pool.ntp.org";
const long gmtOffset_sec = 3600;
const int daylightOffset_sec = 3600;

const byte start_byte = 0x7E; 
const byte stop_byte = 0x7E;

const int max_wait_time_for_reading_data = 1100;
int delay_before_reading_data = 1000;

const int message_length = 114;
byte message[message_length];
byte buffer[90];
bool use_test_data = false;
byte testData[123] = {0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                      0x00, 0x00, 0x7e};

I already used different ESP32s and tried to read the signal without the decryption routine, however nothing seems to be working. How can this be fixed?

you can use TeePrint from my StreamLib to print to two outputs at once

The SmartMeter uses the DLMS protocol.

In main loop, you are calling 'readMessage()' and filling 'message' with serial data. After that , you are passing 'message' to 'printBytesToHex' and this function does not deal with leading zeros.
The function 'print_array' seems to deal with leading zeros. You can try using it or change 'printBytesToHex' to:
void printBytesToHex(byte array[], unsigned int len) 
{

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        Serial.print(message[i]>>4, HEX);
        Serial.print(message[i]&0x0F, HEX);
        
        TelnetStream.print(message[i]>>4, HEX);
        TelnetStreamrial.print(message[i]&0x0F, HEX);
    }
    Serial.print("\n");
    TelnetStream.print("\n");
}

