# Converting IP Address bytes to integer

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, windows-server-2008-x64

For example:

**1. To convert 32-bit IP address (IPv4):**

> ```
> unsigned char ByteAddress[4];
> unsigned int* IntegerAddress;
>
> IntegerAddress = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*> &ByteAddress ;
> ```

Then I can use IntegerAddress to compare ip addresses.

**2. To convert 128-bit IP address (IPv6):**

> ```
> unsigned char ByteAddress[16];
> uint64_t* LongAddress;
>
> LongAddress = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*> &ByteAddress
> ```

Then I can use LongAddress [0] and LongAddress[1] to compare ip addresses.

Is it preferred over using bit shift operators (as it is quicker) ?
Is it good programming practice? Would it work for all platforms (especially unix and windows 64)  and compilers (C++, VS2010)

Comment: I'd prefer c++ casting with `reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>()` in c++ code, but should be portable as long as you have the same endianess

Comment: I edited it as you suggested. But my main intention is, is it preferred approach of conversion over using bit shift operators.

Comment: @Theolodis It's not portable, there's platform that won't handle that if the char array isn't suitable aligned.

Comment: `int` isn't the same size as `char[4]` on *all* platforms. Example: In 16-bit Windows programs, `int` is 16 bits. It will work on many platforms, though.

Comment: You should be aware that the IP address as transported over the network (and as used in the socket structures) is in network (aka big endian) byte order. You may need to use the [ntohl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) function to get the correct integer representation for your machine architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use unions for that

```
union Int32And4Bytes {
int32_t IntegerValue;
unsigned char ByteArray[4];
};
```

It should be aligned correctly, IIRC.

Comment: I had thought of this initially but there is lot of confusion over use of union for reinterpretation of data. Many says that results will be unpredictable depends on compilers and platforms. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c

Comment: The most correct way is to use bit shift operations. But you should detect endianess.

Comment: Shift operators works regardless of endianness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness

Comment: This does not work in C++ due to type punning. It violates the standard (it's valid in C only). It might work in some compilers but you shouldn't depend on it.