# Where to find / how to simulate a JVM on a big endian system?

Tags: jvm, endianness

I'd like to test some code in a JVM with

```
java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder() == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN
```

Is it possible to find any online compiler with such behaviour? Is it possible to simulate it (maybe using VirtualBox for a virtual machine, or something like that)?

Comment: What would the purpose of that be? You know you can't detect endianness within the language, right? It doesn't change how any bit shifting or masking works.

Comment: Doesn't it? I though something like this http://ideone.com/f9oQRD would output 65536 only in little endian systems. Why do you say that it doesn't change how any bit shifting or masking works?

Comment: (I know this question is a dupe but I can't seem to find it. Oh well.) No, it doesn't change it. Bit shifting is defined on the logical value of the number. When you shift numbers left that is equivalent to multiplying. When you shift [non-negative] numbers right, that is equivalent to dividing. Endianness only affects the underlying storage of the bytes of the number in memory, which you can't detect like that.

Comment: I would be more confortable if you could link to a Java documentation page.

Comment: [Java Language Specification §15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19): "The value of n << s is n left-shifted s bit positions; this is equivalent (even if overflow occurs) to multiplication by two to the power s". Also see these questions for C: [bitwise operators and "Endianness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness) and [Does Bit Shift Depends on Endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184789/does-bit-shift-depends-on-endianness). It is true in all languages: shifting is independent of CPU endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: buy a big endian machine like a SPARC workstation.

Or you can try different emulators but those will be very slow and difficult.

Look at this blog post:

http://omega.cs.iit.edu/~bharatkris/blog/?p=211

He uses QEMU which I have never used but it sounds like it does the trick. http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page

VirtualBox relies on the underlying CPU architecture so if you have a little endian cpu (Intel) then it won't be able to run.