# How to set the MSB 4-bits of an integer irrespective of the endianity?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Revised Question -

How to calculate the mask-bits irrespective of the size of integer type?
I want to calculate the mask of first 4-bits, when I don't the size of integer.

I have two options to set the MSB 4-bits in the code -

if little_Endian -

then --

```
  int t  = 54342;

    int k = t<<4;
    int t = (k>>4)|0XF000
```

else big Endian --
then --

```
 int t  = 54342;
    int k = t>>4;
    int t = (k<<4)|0X000F
```

My question is is there any better way to do so. How can I make the code independent of the endianity? I can use union to determine the endianity. However, I want my code to simple. How can I do so?

Comment: Isn't `0xf000` the MSB mask of a 32bit value in any case?

Comment: Endianness does not matter at all here. See answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness).

Comment: What if I want to make a generic program irrespective of the size of int.

Comment: How about `t | (0xf << ((sizeof t)*CHAR_BITS-4)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Endianess is used to interpret the way in which the bytes are stored in the memory. It doesn't dictate how bytes are to be accessed if you are directly referring the variable without any pointer operations.

Which means, the below program will produce same result irrespective of the `endianess` of the platform.

```
int main(void)
{
    int num = 0xDEADBEEF;
    int mask = 0xF0000000;

    printf("SET = %X\n", (unsigned int) (num | mask));
    return 0;
}
```