# c Code that reads a 4 byte little endian number from a buffer

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, endianness

I encountered this piece of C code that's existing. I am struggling to understand it.

I supposidly reads a 4 byte unsigned value passed in a buffer (in little endian format) into a variable of type "long".

This code runs on a 64 bit word size, little endian x86 machine - where sizeof(long) is 8 bytes.
My guess is that this code is intended to also run on a 32 bit x86 machine - so a variable of type long is used instead of int for sake of storing value from a four byte input data.

I am having some doubts and have put comments in the code to express what I understand, or what I don't :-)

Please answer questions below in that context

```
void read_Value_From_Four_Byte_Buff( char*input)
{
    /* use long so on 32 bit machine, can still accommodate 4 bytes */ 
    long intValueOfInput;  

    /* Bitwise and of input buffer's byte 0 with 0xFF gives MSB or LSB ?*/
    /* This code seems to assume that assignment will store in rightmost byte - is that true on a x86 machine ?*/
    intValueOfInput =  0xFF & input[0];

    /*left shift byte-1 eight times, bitwise "or" places in 2nd byte frm right*/
    intValueOfInput |= ((0xFF & input[1]) << 8);

    /* similar left shift in mult. of 8 and bitwise "or" for next two bytes */
    intValueOfInput |= ((0xFF & input[2]) << 16);
    intValueOfInput |= ((0xFF & input[3]) << 24);

}
```

My questions

1)  The input buffer is expected to be in "Little endian". But from code looks like assumption here is that it read in as Byte 0 = MSB, Byte 1, Byte 2, Byte 3= LSB.  I thought so because code reads bytes starting from Byte 0, and subsequent bytes ( 1 onwards)  are placed in the target variable after left shifting. Is that how it is or am I getting it wrong ?

2) I feel this is a convoluted way of doing things - is there a simpler alternative to copy value from 4 byte buffer into a long variable ?

3) Will the assumption "that this code will run on a 64 bit machine" will have any bearing on how easily I can do this alternatively? I mean is all this trouble to keep it agnostic to word size ( I assume its agnostic to word size now - not sure though)  ?

Thanks for your enlightenment :-)

Comment: I assume the last two lines should use `input[2]` and `input[3]`, not `input[1]` again.

Comment: In what way is this convoluted?  Each byte is isolated, shifted into place & "inserted" into the result.

Comment: How is `long intValueOfInput` then used - that affects some of the answer?  As code stands now, the entire code may optimize to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The code you are using does indeed treat the input buffer as little endian.  Look how it takes the first byte of the buffer and just assigns it to the variable without any shifting.  If the first byte increases by 1, the value of your result increases by 1, so it is the least-significant byte (LSB).  Left-shifting makes a byte more significant, not less.  Left-shifting by 8 is generally the same as multiplying by 256.
2. I don't think you can get much simpler than this unless you use an external function, or make assumptions about the machine this code is running on, or invoke undefined behavior.  In most instances, it would work to just write `uint32_t x = *(uint32_t *)input;` but this assumes your machine is little endian and I think it might be undefined behavior according to the C standard.
3. No, running on a 64-bit machine is not a problem.  I recommend using types like `uint32_t` and `int32_t` to make it easier to reason about whether your code will work on different architectures.  You just need to include the `stdint.h` header from C99 to use those types.

The right-hand side of the last line of this function might exhibit [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) depending on the data in the input:

```
((0xFF & input[3]) << 24)
```

The problem is that `(0xFF & input[3])` will be a signed `int` (because of integer promotion).  The `int` will probably be 32-bit, and you are shifting it so far to the left that the resulting value might not be representable in an `int`.  The [C standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says this is undefined behavior, and you should really try to avoid that because it gives the compiler a license to do whatever it wants and you won't be able to predict the result.

A solution is to convert it from an `int` to a `uint32_t` before shifting it, using a cast.

Finally, the variable `intValueOfInput` is written to but never used.  Shouldn't you return it or store it somewhere?

Taking all this into account, I would rewrite the function like this:

```
uint32_t read_value_from_four_byte_buff(char * input)
{
    uint32_t x;
    x = 0xFF & input[0];
    x |= (0xFF & input[1]) << 8;
    x |= (0xFF & input[2]) << 16;
    x |= (uint32_t)(0xFF & input[3]) << 24;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: David - Thanks . You mentioned   left-shifting by 8 is generally the same as multiplying by 256.    Isnt this dependent on endianness that left shift once will multiply by 2 and right shift once will divide by 2 ?   How come is that true if MSB/LSB positions are swapped with endianness ?   I can create a new question for that if warrented

Comment: I saw the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness :-)

Answer (score 3):

1. You have it backwards. When you left shift, you're putting into more significant bits. So `(0xFF & input[3]) << 24)` puts Byte 3 into the MSB.
2. This is the way to do it in standard C. POSIX has the function [`ntohl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) that converts from network byte order to a native 32-bit integer, so this is usually used in Unix/Linux applications.
3. This will not work exactly the same on a 64-bit machine, unless you use `unsigned long` instead of `long`. As currently written, the highest bit of `input[3]` will be put into the sign bit of the result (assuming a twos-complement machine), so you can get negative results. If `long` is 64 bits, all the results will be positive.

Comment: Also don't forget that `char` is typically signed - would expect well written code would have used `uint8_t` instead of `char`, and `uint32_t` (or one of its variants) instead of `long`.

Comment: I have a strong feeling the OP didn't get all the types right when he copied the code, just like he got the array indexes wrong.

Comment: @Brendan, Barmar , Thanks - indeed the code isnt as well written as it should have been. I am now introducing Standard Integer Types in it - hopefully to get more definitive behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

From the code, Byte 0 is LSB, Byte 3 is MSB. But there are some typos. The lines should be

```
intValueOfInput |= ((0xFF & input[2]) << 16);
intValueOfInput |= ((0xFF & input[3]) << 24);
```

You can make the code shorter by dropping 0xFF but using the type "unsigned char" in the argument type.

To make the code shorter, you can do:

```
long intValueOfInput = 0;
for (int i = 0, shift = 0; i < 4; i++, shift += 8)
    intValueOfInput |= ((unsigned char)input[i]) << shift;
```

Comment: Danke - thank you ( your name sounds like thank you in a European language :-) ) -- I corrected the typos