# Interaction between endian-ness and bitwise comparison with register

Tags: x86

I believe this piece of code works, but it really seems like it shouldn't, unless ax is being compared with 0000 1010 instead of 1010 0000. Isn't it not supposed to matter whether data is stored in little or big endian format?

Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
mov    al, es:100h
mov    ah, 0
and    ax, 0A0h
cmp    ax, 20h
...
```

Isn't the value is ax something like this:

```
mov    al, es:100h  ; ax = ???? ????
mov    ah, 0        ; ax = 0000 ????
and    ax, 0A0h     ; ax = 0000 0000 or ax = 0000 ?0?0
cmp    ax, 20h      ; only useful if ax = 0000 ?0?0
...
```

Clearly there's a rule that I don't know here. An explanation would be super helpful.

EDIT: I should mention that I have looked for an answer but could not find one. For instance, this thread only made it seem more like the code must be wrong. But I'm pretty confident it works: [Bitwise operators and "endianness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endian-ness only matters when fetching multi-byte values from memory. In your example, the first line fetches a single byte from memory, so endian-ness is not an issue.

When you hard-code constants in assembly, they read from left to right, just like normal numbers. So the constant `0A0h` has `00000000` as the high byte (corresponding to `ah`) and `10100000` as the low byte (corresponding to `al`).

You do seem to be confused about the number of bits in the register. `AX` is a sixteen bit register. So the commenting the code using binary, the comments should be

```
mov    al, es:100h  ; ax = ???? ???? ???? ????
mov    ah, 0        ; ax = 0000 0000 ???? ????
and    ax, 0A0h     ; ax = 0000 0000 ?0?0 0000
cmp    ax, 20h      ; compare with 0000 0000 0010 0000
```

Comment: Actually, depending on what flags are tested after the `cmp`, it could be doing multiple things.  e.g. `jg` would branch if `al` was `0x80` or `0xA0`.  `jge` would branch if either bit was set (in which case the `cmp` is redundant, and `jnz` after the `and`, or after `test al, 0A0h` would do it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, I changed the last comment to be more generic :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a problem here. Your first instruction is:

```
mov    al, es:100h
```

This stores an arbitrary value in the least significant byte. Next you do:

```
mov    ah, 0
```

This zeroes out the most significant byte. Therefore `ax` is between `0` and `0xff`.

Now you `and` it with the value `0xA0`:

```
and    ax, 0A0h
```

And last you compare the `ax` register with the value `0x20`:

```
cmp    ax, 20h
```

At no point in this series of operations does endianness factor into play. Consider:

```
mov    al, es:100h ;         ax = ???? ???? ???? ????
mov    ah, 0       ;         ax = 0000 0000 ???? ????
and    ax, 0A0h    ;         ax = 0000 0000 ?0?0 0000
cmp    ax, 20h     ; compare with 0000 0000 0010 0000
```

Alternatively we can write this with the bytes reversed so that the most significant byte is to the right:

```
mov    al, es:100h ;         ax = ???? ???? ???? ????
mov    ah, 0       ;         ax = ???? ???? 0000 0000
and    ax, 0A0h    ;         ax = ?0?0 0000 0000 0000
cmp    ax, 20h     ; compare with 0010 0000 0000 0000
```

As you can see you should get the exact same result regardless of endianness.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, the `mov  ah, 0` has no effect on the flags after the `cmp`.  The top half of `ax` is already zeroed by the `and  ax, 0A0h`.

Depending on what condition you want to branch on, the flags set by the `and` might be sufficient.  You left out the next instruction, so we can't tell you what the code is actually testing, and whether it could have been done with just a `test` instead of `and / cmp`.